# Are vector bundles acyclic for $\Gamma_c$?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, sheaf-theory

Let $X$ be a paracompact topological space or a manifold (which is not a particular case since the structure sheaves are different). It is well-known that vector bundles (more generally, $\mathcal{O}_X$-modules) are soft, hence acyclic for $\Gamma$.

**I wonder if the same holds for $\Gamma_c$.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, at least if $X$ is locally compact.

A useful reference is Bredon's book. In brief, soft sheaves are in particular $c$-soft (they satisfy the softness condition for *compact* subsets of $X$ as opposed to all closed subsets of $X$). On a locally compact space, $c$-soft sheaves are $\Gamma_c$-acyclic. Bredon states a more general version of this for an arbitrary "family of supports" $\Phi$, where "locally compact" becomes "the family of supports $\Phi$ is paracompactifying".